# How to set initial date range for Air datepicker

Tags: javascript

I have created a date range selector using Air date picker and it is awesome! Now the problem is I cannot show the previously selected date ( comes from the databases ) range on date picker after the page refresh. I have looked into the documentation and it's has a startDate but no endDate.

Comment: You can use like this `<input type="text"
    data-range="true"
    data-multiple-dates-separator=" - "
    data-language="en"
    class="datepicker-here"/>`

Comment: `data-range="true"` and it will select the range

Comment: Use
`{range: true}`
for choosing range of dates. As dates separator
multipleDatesSeparator
will be used.

Comment: For possibility to select same date two times, you should set
`{toggleSelected: false}`.

Comment: @objectif  I think my question not clear, so I have made some changes to it, sorry for my bad English